# How to see the predicates added by a VPD in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, row-level-security

The predicates added by a Row Level Security policy do not show in the 10046 trace file. One  suggestion is to use the 10053 (optimizer) trace to see the VPD predicates, but it is difficult to set the 10053 trace on a given session from another session.

Is there any other way to see what predicates were added by an RLS policy ?

Scenario : The RLS policy is applied on a query in session #1.  We need to analyse what happens in session #1 from  session #2.

The database 10g is Oracle 10g.

Comment: This question is a legitimate database programming question and should not have been closed.

Comment: This Q seems more appropiate for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ than StackOverflow. It's too off-topic here.

Comment: @WimtenBrink - Why?  In my experience DBAs do not get involved in the implementation of Row Level Security policies.  Unless your contention is that any question touching on databases belongs on the dba.se site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a user who has access to [V$VPD_POLICY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3121.htm#sthref3707).  By default that would be just the SYSDBA users, so you'll probably need a DBA to grant you access on the view.  The view ties predicates to SQL statements.  You'll need to get the SQL_ID from V$SQLAREA, because that gives you the ADDRESS, which is the only mechanism to link the SQL statement to the right row in V$SESSION.

Actually the order of access is: V$SESSION gives you the ADDRESS of the last statement executed by session 1.  You use that to find its SQL_ID in V$SQLAREA, which in turn allows you to link to V$VPD_POLICY.

So you need access to several of the V$ views.  But if you're tuning you should have access to them anyway, except V$VPD_POLICY.

Comment: Yes I am able to see the predicates through V$VPD_POLICY. Is this the only reliable way to get at the VPD predicates ?

Comment: Why is this off topic ? We are not allowed to ask questions about the Oracle database ?

Comment: Well I have amassed my rep largely on the basis of answering database programming questions.  There are some database questions asked here which more properly belong on dba.stackexhange.com but the closers have voted to migrated it there.  Interestingly none of the voters appears to major in database programming, so I guess they voted to close the question simply because they didn't understand it.